# Why using kafka with flink

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

I'm currently discovering the domain of Stream processing with flink. However, most of the specialized articles, I read so far, talk about flink AND kafka. However I did not find a clear explaination why this duo seems so logic and  explaining what kafka does that flink can not and vice versa.

So far I found the following:
- flink can not PROCESS_CONTINUOUSLY with readCsvFile and kafka could support in this aspect,
- kafka can do stream aggregation but it seems limited (not sure) compared to kafka.

So, please don't hesitate to add your knowledge AND experience you had so far with these systems. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is true that at first sight the difference is not obvious.

Apache Kafka is a solution to deal with real-time information and route it to consumers in a quick way, meaning it is a **message broker**.

Apache Flink is a **stream processing framework**. It involves data in-memory distributed computing.

That being said, basically, Kafka will have the role of the message router, and Apache Flink will process the data.

As you can see on the example schema below, Kafka would allow to publish messages from heterogenous sources and Apache Flink will process these data by applying windowing or reduce functions.

[image]

If you look into the Kafka documentation, they introduced a new feature on top of Kafka called Kafka Stream (which is not part of the original Kafka). This is also a stream processing framework which have the ability to process data as Apache Flink do.